# How to enable network on DLCBoot's mini windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, bootable-media, hiren

My hdd died a couple of days ago and I am using a DLC to boot up from a flash drive, but the network services seems to be uninstalled/disabled.

Is there anyway to install/enable the network?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: What PC hardware is it running on?

Comment: DLC BOOT 2016 v3.2 with mini Windows 10 x64

Comment: Try this one>>>>https://www.filehorse.com/download-dlc-boot/

Comment: Acer Aspire 7715z, 4 gb ram, Dual Core 2.3 ghz, Qualcom Atheros AR8132 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller.

Comment: I'll try in a copule of days and I'll let you know

Comment: Be sure and make the bootable usb on the PC you are going to use it on, some of these rescue disks will pull drivers from the current system when executed.

Comment: @DavidRios, do not add comments, instead, edit your question to include all information. BTW, try running from a Ubuntu Live USB, which should access the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I tried under both DLC BOOT versions 3.2 and 3.6 and the network works correctly, the problem was when I tried to log on a remote computer. It didn't matter if the user and password were correct or not, the system throwed the same error (see image link below) and in some occassions: The Server service is not started.

Error image link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xZqE.jpg

I kept looking and found the answer here:
https://superuser.com/a/1126123